# unable to install libzt package on windows system

Tags: python, pypi, zerotier

I'm trying to install libzt package on windows, and using python 3.11.3, but I'm getting following error.
Although this package is available on pypi.

C:\Users\hp\Desktop\test>pip install libzt
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libzt (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for libzt

Please help.

Thanks

I tried to install older version of libzt but I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [PyPI project page for libzt](https://pypi.org/project/libzt/) and scroll down to the 'Operating Systems' section, you'll see the following:

> **Operating System**
>
> - MacOS
> - POSIX :: BSD
> - POSIX :: Linux
> - Unix

Windows is not in this list. Therefore you cannot install `libzt` on Windows.